# Why it is said if a black cat crosses your path you should not move ahead?

Tags: puranas, practice, superstitions, omens

I have been told by my elders if a black cat crosses your path you should not move ahead

Can any one shed light on this? Is this a myth or are there any references in Puranas/Scripts or so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per this [Agni Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/agni/bookview.php?chapnum=14) chapter, a cat crossing one's path (from right to left) is in fact considered a good omen.

> **Good Omens**: Good omens while leaving house are facing white flowers, full vessels, meat, distant sounds, goat, cow, horse,
>   elephant, fire, gold, silver, sword, umbrella, fruits, butter or curd,
>   sugarcane, sound of thunder, lightning, dead body without anybody
>   crying, donkey’s braying; buffallo crossing from left to right;
>   **horse, cats, donkeys, from right to left**

On the other hand , following are few examples of bad omens:

> Bad omens are facing cotton, dry grass, cowdung, coal, leather, hair,
>   a lunatic, chandala, widow, ashes, bones, sound of musical
>   instruments, break down of vehicle, fall of umbrella on head, recall
>   back before journey and so on.’

Comment: I think black cats are exception to this. Many people still believe black cats as inauspicious.

Comment: @TheDestroyer No, that's a myth. In earlier times, when the people used to travel, they did it on horses and with cows. But in night time, whenever a cat crossed their path, their glowing eyes scared the horses and cows. Just to relax the horses and cows, people stopped their journey for some time. But now, the meaning of cat crossing path has completely changed. People started believing that cats crossing is a sign of bad omen.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria haha. i think you read this on Quora. But i have personally seen bad omens happening to people when they encountered black cat.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Well Swami Vivekananda used to say always use logic and never blindly believe stuff. And the glowing eyes of cats at night times is a true fact. Bad things happened to people who encountered black cat is because they themselves accepted the fact that something bad is going to happen. Read "Power of the subconscious mind" - the greatest book of all time. You may ask how is this book is even related - once you read it, you'll know why.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Here is the book: http://www.amazon.in/Power-your-Subconscious-Mind/dp/8192910962?ie=UTF8&keywords=power%20of%20subconscious%20mind&qid=1477326182&ref_=sr_1_1&sr=8-1

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria i agree with "glowing eyes of black cat". But we need to consider "Science of Sooksha or subtle world". when we train up brain, we tend to think like that. This is also true. But all things may not happen as we are training our brains or by having prejudices. Yes, mail me.

Comment: black cat crossing from LEFT to RIGHT is still bad omen